# Run jOOQ <-> Liquibase in silent mode

Tags: gradle, liquibase, jooq

I have set jOOQ configuration with Liquibase database, all is working good. I want to execute `gradle generateJooq` task in silent mode, but there are some other logs got from liquibase for anyway for some reason, is there any property that I can set to prevent them?

jOOQ setup:

```
jooqConfiguration.apply {
    logging = if (gradle.startParameter.logLevel == LogLevel.QUIET)
        org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging.WARN
    else
        org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging.INFO
    generator.apply {
        database.apply {
            name = "org.jooq.meta.extensions.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabase"
            properties = listOf(
                Property()
                    .withKey("scripts")
                    .withValue("/changelog/changelog-master.yaml")
            )
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Logs that I still got while running `gradle clean build -q`:

```
02:25:43 INFO Set default schema name to PUBLIC
02:25:43 INFO Successfully acquired change log lock
02:25:43 INFO Creating database history table with name: PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
02:25:43 INFO Reading from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
Running Changeset: /changelog/changelog-generated.yaml::empty::tpd
02:25:43 INFO Empty change did nothing
02:25:43 INFO ChangeSet /changelog/changelog-generated.yaml::empty::tpd ran successfully in 0ms
02:25:43 INFO Successfully released change log lock
```

Comment: The documentation for Liquibase's logging is here: https://docs.liquibase.com/parameters/log-level.html. I must admit, I couldn't mute it myself after a few attempts...